# Is there a way to forward TTN_NEEDTEXT to CFrameWnd?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, tooltip

I have an application that already deals with the generating of tooltips.  I am modifying a CWnd derived class that has a parent frame.  It doesn't implement tooltips.

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa23xtsw.aspx), I can get tooltips to show up by adding the following code:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyWindow, CWnd)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXTW, 0, 0xFFFF, OnToolTipNotify)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXTA, 0, 0xFFFF, OnToolTipNotify)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyWindow::OnToolTipNotify(UINT id, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(id);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pResult);

    // need to handle both ANSI and UNICODE versions of the message
    TOOLTIPTEXTA* pTTTA = (TOOLTIPTEXTA*)pNMHDR;
    TOOLTIPTEXTW* pTTTW = (TOOLTIPTEXTW*)pNMHDR;
    CStringA strTipText;
    UINT_PTR nID = pNMHDR->idFrom;
    if (pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA && (pTTTA->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND) ||
        pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTW && (pTTTW->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND))
    {
        // idFrom is actually the HWND of the tool
        nID = ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)nID);
    }

    if (nID != 0) // will be zero on a separator
        strTipText.Format("Control ID = %d", nID);

    if (pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXTA)
    {
        strncpy_s(pTTTA->szText, sizeof(pTTTA->szText), strTipText,
            strTipText.GetLength() + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, strTipText, strTipText.GetLength() + 1,
            pTTTW->szText, sizeof(pTTTW->szText) / (sizeof pTTTW->szText[0]));
    }

    return TRUE;    // message was handled
}
```

I can use `GetParentFrame()` to get the frame window, so I'd like to leverage the tooltip code that is already in place so that I get a consistent look.  Is there some way that I can forward the `TTN_NEEDTEXT` message so that it gets handled by the frame window?

Comment: What does `GetParentFrame()` return, a HWND or a CWindow?

Comment: @andlabs Not at my desk, but I think it would return a class, not an HWND.

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest using Unicode strings and then converting *to* `CP_ACP` when needed, not the other way around, to be safe in the presence of user input contributing to a built string.

Comment: Thanks @andlabs, I didn't write the code, but I'll take that under advisement. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your message map, you use `ON_NOTIFY_whatever`, which should hint that the message that `TTN_NEEDTEXT` uses is `WM_NOTIFY` — and indeed this is the case. So you can just produce the `WM_NOTIFY` yourself and send it to the parent.

[The documentation for `WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx) says `wParam` is the control's identifier and `lParam` is the `NMHDR` pointer. There's an example on the bottom of the page that shows `wParam` is just the `idFrom` member of the `NMHDR`, so you have everything you need to reconstruct the message:

```
LRESULT lr = this->GetParentFrame()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, pNMHDR->idFrom, (LPARAM) pNMHDR);
```

When you should issue this call is up to what you need to do. In this case, you would probably want to make it the first call, override your string, and return `TRUE`. I'm not fully sure, though.

> *Note: if MFC provides a function to do this, I don't know it; I personally don't use MFC, but the concepts are the same.*

So what about the return value from that `SendMessage()`? Well, you can return it via `pResult` (for instance, if you're just tweaking the parent's alterations slightly), or you can ignore it and return a custom value. But for `TTN_NEEDTEXT`, it won't matter; [`TTN_NEEDTEXT` doesn't care what the LRESULT is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760293(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So what happens to the `pResult`?

Comment: Oh I completely missed that parameter! Editing answer.

Comment: Cool, so it's ignored.  Is there some documentation on how to read these M$ pages.  I always have difficulty trying to understand what it all means and it's annoying having to go out and ask all the time. :(

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to work.  It forwards the message, but it doesn't generate the extended tooltips to keep the look the same.  I get the text but not the correct tooltip look.

Comment: I'm going to give this to you as it appears that my question was wrong. I'll post another correctly asking what I need.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086544/need-to-figure-out-how-to-reuse-tooltip-code-to-get-a-consistent-look-across-the) is actually the question that I intended.